# How do I configure Guice in Play Framework to require an @Inject annotation for empty constructors?

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, guice, playframework-2.5

I'd like to prevent Guice in Play Framework (2.5.x) from injecting classes without the `@Inject()` annotation on the constructor. Guice provides the [`requireAtInjectOnConstructors` configuration option](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.1/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requireAtInjectOnConstructors--) on `Binder` which achieves this.

The Play documentation describes two ways to customize Guice:

1. [Programmatic Bindings](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Programmatic-bindings)
2. [Extending the GuiceApplicationLoader](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Advanced:-Extending-the-GuiceApplicationLoader)

I first tried customizing the Binder in my `Module$configure` method:

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule

class Module extends AbstractModule {

  override def configure() = {
    binder().requireAtInjectOnConstructors()
  }

}
```

When I then run the application I see the following errors:

```
! @7115jkk8o - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Explicit @Inject annotations are required on constructors, but play.api.inject.DefaultApplicationLifecycle has no constructors annotated with @Inject.
  at play.api.inject.BuiltinModule.bindings(BuiltinModule.scala:42):
  Binding(class play.api.inject.DefaultApplicationLifecycle to self) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)

2) Explicit @Inject annotations are required on constructors, but play.api.http.NoHttpFilters has no constructors annotated with @Inject.
  at play.utils.Reflect$.bindingsFromConfiguration(Reflect.scala:53):
  Binding(interface play.api.http.HttpFilters to ConstructionTarget(class play.api.http.NoHttpFilters)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
```

When I extend the GuiceApplicationBuilder to set this configuration:

```
import play.api.ApplicationLoader
import play.api.inject.guice.{ GuiceApplicationBuilder, GuiceApplicationLoader }

class CustomApplicationLoader extends GuiceApplicationLoader {

  override def builder(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): GuiceApplicationBuilder = {
    initialBuilder.requireAtInjectOnConstructors()
  }

}
```

I see the same errors with this approach.

The error messages indicate to me that the Play Framework itself relies on Guice injecting classes with empty constructors which are not annotated with `@Inject()`.

Is there a way I can configure Guice to require the `@Inject()` annotation for classes in my application without affecting the Play Framework Guice configuration?

Comment: out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: a) Report this to the Play framework.  b) If you put all your stuff in a `PrivateModule`, the `requireAtInjectOnConstructors()` will be local to that module.

Comment: @rethab this helps avoid certain classes of bugs. For instance, I'd like to inject an instance of a class I don't control. That class may have a constructor without any arguments, and one with arguments. That class may need some setup before it can be used and passing arguments to the constructor sets the instance up. Guice will be perfectly happy to inject an instance of that class without me realizing that I need to configure that instance prior to using it.

Comment: @TavianBarnes I tried to modify my module to extend `PrivateModule` instead of `AbstractModule`. While this didn't cause the issues with the Play Framework I document in the original question, it didn't address my root problem. The class with an empty constructor that exists in my project is still being injected. [The `PrivateModule` docs](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/PrivateModule.html) say something about nested environments; I guess in the environment within which Play operates the binder won't have `requireAtInjectOnConstructors` on.

Comment: @TavianBarnes OK, I submitted an issue to the Play Framework: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6384